# div horizontal scrolled to left from center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to apply animation jquery effect to div having list of category which is at center of page.when i am clicking on 1st category then that initial div should move to left from center and new div should appear from right to left.when clicked on 2nd category 1st div having content should move to right and 2nd content div should appear.

effect mostly same like http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47602/index.html
I am able to use viewport to implement div moving from right to left but 1st transition of div having category list from center to left is not achieved.

Thank u

JS

```
var navClick = function() {
    $viewport = $('#viewport');
    $targetElem = $('#content' + $(this).data('target'));
    $active = $viewport.find('.active');
    $active.animate({'right': '-' + $active.width() + 'px'}, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $targetElem.animate({'right': '100px'}, function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
};

$(function() {
   $('nav span').on('click', navClick); 
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nehab123/qtt6L/)

Comment: Can you show us what code [HTML/CSS/JS/JQ] you do have in a JSfiddle?

Comment: I have uploaded code on fidle http://jsfiddle.net/nehab123/qtt6L/

Comment: Are you actually linking JQuery? I added it to the JSFiddle and got some functionailty: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/qtt6L/1/

Comment: Yes i think i did not link library.I was expecting same effect as it appears now after linking library 1.10.1.

Comment: I have used aminate.css to add bouncing effect with jquery.But its not working completely  jsfiddle.net/nehab123/Q4nK4/2/

Comment: You don't link to the proper animate.min.css file. Github is no CDN and also you didn't link to the raw file. Right: //cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/2.1.0/animate.min.css